# Preloader That Actually Responds To Loaded Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a preloader that actually represents a "percentage" of loaded content. Not necessarily by a number, but using an animated box (scaling from left to right of window). Currently, I'm using this code to determine how many images are on the page, and build a grid when all the images are loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
num_images = $("img").length;
img_counter = 0;
$("img").css("display", "none");

$(".grid-item").each(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        img_counter++;
        if (img_counter == num_images) {
            console.log(num_images);
            $("img").css("display", "block");
            $('.grid').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                isAnimated: true
            });
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

Then, on window.load I have a preloader that adds a class of "loaded".

```
$('.preloader').addClass('loaded');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.content').css('opacity', 1);
    $('.preloader').css({'transform': 'translateY(-50px)'});
}, 500);
```

This all gives the illusion that there is a loading feature, but it's not actually showing the "loading" process. How can I determine how much of the content is loaded and display that with the width of the preloader?

Here's a basic test page I'm working with. Thanks a ton in advance! I don't necessarily need answers, but guidance or direction.

http://andyrichardson.design/masonry/

Answer (score 1):

Add an onload function for the images and increase the counter when the pnload function trggers (which mean that the image is loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
num_images = $("img").length;
   img_counter = 0;
  $('img').load(function(){
   img_counter++;
   // do your other stuff here
});
}
```